# How to mirror widgets in Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Imagine that you have two pairs of Bokeh widgets:

`widget1 = widgetbox(input1=TextInput(...), multiselect1=MultiSelect(...))`
`widget2 = widgetbox(input2=TextInput(...), multiselect2=MultiSelect(...))`

Both, `multiselect1` and `multiselect2`, are initially populated with the same options, let's say `['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']`.
Both inputs, `input1` and `input2` are used to collect input from user and filter(update) the object in `multiselect` widgets according to that input.
For example, if a user enters `apples` in `input1`, `multiselect1` will get updated and show only `apples`, discarding the others.

The question is how to make both widgets work in tandem or have them mirror each other if you will? So, both widgets will show the same objects, regardless if a user enters text in `input1` or `input2`.

I have tried to create `widget2` as a copy of `widget1`, thinking that both will reference the same object, so, when the object gets updated, either reference, `widget1` and `widget2`, will display the updated object but it doesn't work.
I'm speculating that when Bokeh renders the Python code in JavaScript it assigns a unique ID to each object, and from here they become independent.
If you have an idea, please, let me hear it!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `stocks` example is a good one to refer to:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/stocks/main.py

It's going in the opposite direction, i.e. it's removing whatever is in one ticker from the other, but the principe is the same, update the `options` property of the widget with whatever you need. Here is the relevant portion of the `stocks` example:

```
DEFAULT_TICKERS = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'INTC', 'BRCM', 'YHOO']

def nix(val, lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x != val]

def ticker1_change(attrname, old, new):
    ticker2.options = nix(new, DEFAULT_TICKERS)
    update()

def ticker2_change(attrname, old, new):
    ticker1.options = nix(new, DEFAULT_TICKERS)
    update()
```

So if a user selects `AAPL` from the first select then `AAPL` will be removed from the second. In your case, you would have a callback on the inputs that set the select options appropriately to your use case.

If this is outside the context of a Bokeh server app, then you could also accomplish the same thing with [`CustomJS` callbacks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#userguide-interaction-jscallbacks) instead of Python callbacks.